# Why is boost looking for libboost_*.lib instead of boost_*.lib?

Tags: c++, boost

I compiled the boost libraries using the tagged layout, and because of this I have library files of the form `boost_program_options-mt.lib`. I'm assuming the problem is boost_auto_link or something. I have the pre-processor definition `BOOST_AUTO_LINK_TAGGED`, although I am still getting errors saying that Visual Studio is looking for the `libboost` versions and can't open the file.

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_program_options-mt.lib'
```

How can I fix this so that I can link to the libraries correctly?

> **UPDATE:** For some reason, when I launch my program, I get an error saying that boost_system-mt.dll is missing from my computer. This is very weird since I am not linking to the dynamic libraries, nor do I have dynamic libraries included in my additional libraries directory.

Comment: Looks it it's trying to link with the static libs, rather than the dynamic ones.

Comment: @DanMašek I want to link the static libs in my library directories, except all of my static libs were compiled by b2 as boost_program_options-mt.lib. If that's not the standard, then why would b2 compile them that way? All of my static and dynamic libs have start with boost_ rather than libboost_.

Comment: That's seems unlikely. According to [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#library-naming): "On Windows, only ordinary static libraries use the `lib` prefix; import libraries and DLLs do not." ... "This convention distinguishes the static version of a Boost library from the import library for an identically-configured Boost DLL, which would otherwise have the same name." How did you build your boost to end up in such a state (and as a matter of fact, how do you distinguish them)?

Comment: In C++ --> Code Generation settings, do you see MT or MD switch? I.e. do you link your application with static or dynamic CRT?

Answer (score 1):

From the boost documentation mentioned [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/config/doc/html/index.html):

> **BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB**
>   Tells the config system not to automatically select which libraries to link against. Normally if a compiler supports #pragma lib, then the correct library build variant will be automatically selected and linked against, simply by the act of including one of that library's headers. This macro turns that feature off.

So, I think if you define `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` in your pre-processor definitions, and then add the path of the library to your library path list, it will solve the problem.